# Server redirection in .htaccess changing with the order of RewriteRule statements

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, redirect

I have a .htaccess file where I redirect POST statements to the corresponding PHP script. Strangely, if I have the RewriteRule statements as shown below, the second PHP returns an empty response although it is successfully called (response status code: 200):

```
RewriteRule ^rest some_subdir/api/rest.php
RewriteRule ^restscrape some_subdir/api/restscrape.php
```

However, if I switch the positions of these statements (moving the second statement above the first one), both PHP scripts are called correctly and return the correct response. What is wrong with my script? The syntax in the .htaccess should not depends on indentation or text formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add `$`, i.e.:

```
RewriteRule ^rest$ some_subdir/api/rest.php
RewriteRule ^restscrape$ some_subdir/api/restscrape.php
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the $ for?

Comment: It basically stops the match there.

Comment: Yes. That did it. Thank you!